# How can I store an attribute 'title' in a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

When an user clicks in a button to call high contrast, the page's style is changed and stored in a cookie. Until here, OK. But, from now I want to change the title of this same button according the page's style (Turn on High Contrast / Turn off High Contrast), it even works in the same page, but if I reload the page, the title is not kept, only the style.

What can I do to solve this problem? I thank, since now! =]

```
 function getCookie(strCookie){
var strName = strCookie + "=";
var arrCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i &lt; arrCookies.length; i++) {
var strValorCookie = arrCookies[i];
while (strValorCookie.charAt(0) == ' ') {strValorCookie = strValorCookie.substring(1, strValorCookie.length);}
if (strValorCookie.indexOf(strName) == 0) {return strValorCookie.substring(strName.length, strValorCookie.length);}
} return '';
}

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
var today = new Date(); today.setTime( today.getTime() ); expires = 365; path = '/';
if ( expires ) {expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;}
var expires_date = new Date( today.getTime() + (expires) );
document.cookie = name + "=" +escape( value ) + ( ( expires ) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "" ) + ( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "" ) + ( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) + ( ( secure ) ? ";secure" : "" );
}

function eraseCookie(name) {setCookie(name, '', -1);}

$(document).ready(function() {
var cookieContrast = getCookie("escuro");
if (cookieContrast == "escuro"){$("body").addClass("escuro");}
$(".bt-tema").click(function(){
var x = getCookie("escuro");
if (x == "escuro") {$("body").removeClass("escuro"); eraseCookie("escuro");} else {$("body").addClass("escuro"); setCookie("escuro", "escuro");}
```

This title is changed according the page's style, it's not stored in a cookie though:

```
var title = 'Ativar o alto contraste (Alt+5)' ; if( $("body").hasClass('escuro')){title = 'Desativar o alto contraste (Alt+5)';} $(this).attr('title', title);

    return (false);
    });
    });
```

Comment: Can't you just look at the cookie, and if it has the high contrast value do something like `$('#button_id').text('<button text>');`

Comment: Thanks, man. It's working now. =]